# Need of writing tests again and again

Tags: remix, dapps, testing

I started learning about ethereum and dapps just a week ago.I totally understand the need and importance of writing tests for an ethereum smart contract. But what I didn't understand is that I already spent a lot of time working and testing the contract on remix ide. Still why most of the course instructors and experts focus on writing tests on the local environment again?

Answer (score 0):

Testing a software, or a smart contract, it's the same, is a bit more than making you sure that you have no bugs.
You should read a few articles about why testing software.
A non exhaustive liste of reasons is:

- no having to test manually each time you make a change on your code
- prevention regression
- explain what the code does and what to expect
- give confidence to others as they can see by themselves that it works by running your tests
- ...